# Dual of representations of Lie algebras?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

A **linear represenation** of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a pair $(V, \nabla)$ consisting of a vector space $V$ and a Lie algebra morphism

$$\nabla: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathsf{End}(V),$$
where $\mathsf{End}(V)$ is endowed with the bracket $[T_1, T_2]:=T_1\circ T_2-T_2\circ T_1$.

> **Question 1.** Is there a bijection between the set of representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$ and the set of representations of
>   $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V^*$?

I believe this is the case for given $\nabla$ we can defined $\nabla^*: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathsf{End}(V^*)$ setting $$\nabla_x^*(f):=-f\circ \nabla_x.$$ We need this minus sign in order to get a morphism of Lie algebras. On the other hand, given $\nabla^*$ we define $\nabla_x: V\longrightarrow V$ by duality as $$f(\nabla_x v)=-\nabla_x^*(f)(v),\forall f\in V^*.$$

The minus sign here is for the definition to be consistent with $\nabla_x^*$ we defined previously.

I have a second question. I'm guessing any representation $\nabla^*: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathsf{End}(V^*)$ induces $$\Lambda^k \nabla^*: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathsf{End}(\Lambda^k V^*)$$ by:

$$(\Lambda^k \nabla^*)_x(f_1\wedge \ldots \wedge f_k):=\sum_{j=1}^k f_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \nabla_x^* f_j\wedge\ldots \wedge f_k.$$

This is the only linear extension of $\nabla_x^*$ to $\Lambda^k V^*$. Probabily we can define $\Lambda^k \nabla: \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathsf{End}(\Lambda^k V)$ by $$(\Lambda^k \nabla)_x(v_1, \ldots, v_k):=-\sum_{j=1}^k v_1\wedge \ldots \wedge \nabla_xv_j\wedge \ldots \wedge v_k,\quad (I)$$ and $\Lambda^k \nabla^*$ will then become the dual representaion of $\Lambda^k \nabla$.

> **Question 2.** Does every representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\Lambda^k V^*$ arises from a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V^*$ according to $(I)$?

I don't think this is true anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Q1: what does equivalent mean? (and what if $\dim V=\infty$?). Q2: what is a "representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\Lambda^k V^*$"? If we are forgetting the fact that $V^*$ carries a rep of $\mathfrak{g}$ then $\Lambda^k V^*$ is just a vector space, so of course there are different reps of $\mathfrak{g}$ on it in general.

Comment: Both questions are not entirely clear. What does "equivalent" mean in the first question? In the second question, did you mean to ask "Does every representation ... have this form?" (This question have negative answer already for $sl(2)$.)

Comment: I guess I made it clearer.